# Native ad causing app to crash when fetching relatime data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, native-ads

I have an app in which I am fetching data from realtime database of Firebase and then using it in a RecyclerView. Then I went through the tutorial and added Native ads as items in the recyclerview by updating the recyclerAdapter. Everything works fine. But whenever I change data in firebase with app running it crashes. This is my Activity and Adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener
        , ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener{

    //Firebase Related
    private DatabaseReference mMainDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMatchesListDatabase;

    private SliderLayout mMainSlider;
    private DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView;

    private ArrayList<String> adUrl = new ArrayList<>();

    private TextView mUpdateTv;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    //Native Express ad related
    // A Native Express ad is placed in every nth position in the RecyclerView.
    public static final int ITEMS_PER_AD = 4;

    // The Native Express ad height.
    private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT = 132;

    // The Native Express ad unit ID.
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-9016057534718300/6254629155";

    // The RecyclerView that holds and displays Native Express ads and menu items.
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    // List of Native Express ads and MenuItems that populate the RecyclerView.
    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Admob related important code*/
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView_main);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mUpdateTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updates_tv);

        mMatchesListDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("matcheslist");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_matches_list);

        // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView.
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Specify a linear layout manager.
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Update the RecyclerView item's list with menu items and Native Express ads.
        addMatchesListFromFirebase();
        //addNativeExpressAds();
        //setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds();



        //Setup the progress dialog that is displayed later when authenticating with Firebase
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we load data for you!");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);


        mMainSlider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_slider);

        mMainDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mMainDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mProgressDialog.show();

                //Match Updates Section of firebase database
                String update = "";
                for(DataSnapshot eachMatchUpdate: dataSnapshot.child("matchupdates").getChildren()) {

                    update = update + "  * " + eachMatchUpdate.getValue().toString();

                }

                mUpdateTv.setText(update);



                //Ads Section of firebase database
                adUrl.clear();
                //Data for Slider images
                for (DataSnapshot eachAdUrl : dataSnapshot.child("ads").getChildren()) {
                    adUrl.add(String.valueOf(eachAdUrl.getValue()));
                }

                //To shuffle the ads
                Collections.shuffle(adUrl);

                for (int i = 0; i < adUrl.size(); i++) {
                    defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(MainActivity.this);
                    //Initialize a SliderLayout
                    defaultSliderView
                            .image(adUrl.get(i))
                            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                            .setOnSliderClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                    mMainSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
                }

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // Specify an adapter.
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MainActivityAdapter(MainActivity.this, mRecyclerViewItems);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mMainSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.DepthPage);
        mMainSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mMainSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mMainSlider.setDuration(4000);
        mMainSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    private void addMatchesListFromFirebase() {

        mMatchesListDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot eachMatch : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MatchesList match = eachMatch.getValue(MatchesList.class);
                    mRecyclerViewItems.add(match);
                }

                addNativeExpressAds();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void addNativeExpressAds() {

        // Loop through the items array and place a new Native Express ad in every ith position in
        // the items List.
        for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {

            final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
            //Extra here
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, adView);
        }

        mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final float scale = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
                for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {

                    final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                            (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                    final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                    final CardView cardViewMatchContainer = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.match_card_view);
                    final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                            - cardView.getPaddingRight();

                    Log.d("cardviewheight", String.valueOf((int)(cardViewMatchContainer.getHeight()/scale)));
                    AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                    adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Adapter Code

```
public class MainActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    // A menu item view type.
    private static final int MATCH_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    // The Native Express ad view type.
    private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    // An Activity's Context.
    private final Context mContext;

    // The list of Native Express ads and menu items.
    private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;

    public MainActivityAdapter(Context context, List<Object> recyclerViewItems) {
        mContext = context;
        mRecyclerViewItems = recyclerViewItems;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new view for a menu item view or a Native Express ad view
     * based on the viewType. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
     */
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {

            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE :
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                    viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_ad_container,
                    viewGroup, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
            case MATCH_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE :
                // fall through
            default:View matchItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.match_item_container, viewGroup, false);
                return new MatchItemViewHolder(matchItemLayoutView);


        }
    }

    /**
     *  Replaces the content in the views that make up the menu item view and the
     *  Native Express ad view. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (viewType) {

            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder =
                        (NativeExpressAdViewHolder) holder;
                NativeExpressAdView adView =
                        (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
                ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressHolder.itemView;

                // The NativeExpressAdViewHolder recycled by the RecyclerView may be a different
                // instance than the one used previously for this position. Clear the
                // NativeExpressAdViewHolder of any subviews in case it has a different
                // AdView associated with it, and make sure the AdView for this position doesn't
                // already have a parent of a different recycled NativeExpressAdViewHolder.

                adCardView.removeAllViews();


                if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                    ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
                }

                // Add the Native Express ad to the native express ad view.
                adCardView.addView(adView);
                break;

            case MATCH_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            default:
                MatchItemViewHolder matchItemHolder = (MatchItemViewHolder) holder;
                MatchesList match = (MatchesList) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

                // This is used to pass the key which is creating some problems
                matchItemHolder.itemView.setTag(position);

                matchItemHolder.setKeys(match);

                matchItemHolder.mSeriesName.setText(match.getSeries());
                matchItemHolder.mTeam1Name.setText(match.getTeam1());
                matchItemHolder.mTeam2Name.setText(match.getTeam2());
                matchItemHolder.mAddTime.setText("Added " + match.getTime() + " IST");

                Picasso.with(matchItemHolder.viewholderContext)
                        .load(match.getImaget1())
                        //.placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .resize(256,256)
                        .into(matchItemHolder.mTeam1Image);

                Picasso.with(matchItemHolder.viewholderContext)
                        .load(match.getImaget2())
                        //.placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .resize(256,256)
                        .into(matchItemHolder.mTeam2Image);

                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerViewItems.size();
    }

    /**
     * Determines the view type for the given position.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position % MainActivity.ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE
                    : MATCH_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }


    public class MatchItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mSeriesName, mTeam1Name, mTeam2Name, mAddTime;
        private ImageView mTeam1Image, mTeam2Image;
        private Context viewholderContext;

        private ArrayList<String> tempKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        private MatchesList tempMatchForKey;

        private void setKeys(MatchesList key) {
            tempMatchForKey = key;
        }

        public MatchItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewholderContext = itemView.getContext();
            mSeriesName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.series_name);
            mTeam1Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team1_name);
            mTeam2Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team2_name);
            mAddTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_time);
            mTeam1Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team1_image);
            mTeam2Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team2_image);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // This is used to pass the key which is creating some problems
                    int position=(Integer)v.getTag();

                    Intent singleMatchIntent = new Intent(viewholderContext, MatchActivity.class);
                    singleMatchIntent.putExtra("MATCHSELECTIONKEY", tempMatchForKey.getKey());
                    viewholderContext.startActivity(singleMatchIntent);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat Window

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: in.protechlabz.www.dream11predictionguru, PID: 9397
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView cannot be cast to in.protechlabz.www.dream11predictionguru.model.MatchesList
     at in.protechlabz.www.dream11predictionguru.adapters.MainActivityAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainActivityAdapter.java:107)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:282)
     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:336)
     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:349)
     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:356)
     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:387)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```